# Best approach to css drop shadow technique - non image

Tags: css, roundedcorners-dropshadow

Looking for the best approach for a non-image CSS Drop Shadow technique.

I have a popup that I would like to add a shadow to.

Bonus question:

Can it work with:

- -moz-border-radius
- -webkit-border-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow, see:

```
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/
```

for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell whether it's the best approach, but you might want to check out the [ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit DropShadow](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/DropShadow/DropShadow.aspx) extender. It creates a few styled `div` to simulate the shadow.